# what is the meaning of the term "computation space"?

Tags: computer-science

What is the meaning of the term "computation space"?

I was able to find in wikipedia a very clear explanation of the term "computation time".  I.e. The time required by a deterministic Turing machine M on input x is the total number of state transitions, or steps, the machine makes before it halts and outputs the answer ("yes" or "no"). But I was unable to find a similarly clear definition of "computation space".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computation space denotes the amount of memory required to preform the algorithm (expressed in terms of `n`, the size of the input -- just like with computation time).

Answer (score 3):

The definition was given in the same article you referenced, where space is the number of storage locations (or how much memory) so using your wording

> The space required by a deterministic Turing machine M on input x is the total number of storage locations, or memory, the machine needs before it halts and outputs the answer ("yes" or "no").

Which is why in the Wikipedia article they phrased it as (space or time).

> Analogous definitions can be made for space requirements. Although time and space are the most well-known complexity resources, any complexity measure can be viewed as a computational resource.

Answer (score 0):

Found something on net (please refer for detail) :- http://www.mozart-oz.org/documentation/tutorial/node12.html

A computation space consists in general of a computation store and a set of executing threads. What we have seen so far is a single computation space. When dealing with logic programming a more elaborate structure will arise with multiple nested computation spaces. The general rules for the structure of computation spaces are as follows.

It means that each process loads into memory and their boundary is very well defined.  Getting such process space and loading program each time in memory is difficult is **one of the reason whey thread are invented**.

Each thread has some common processing space such as (stack) and common area (process space where they are created) hence we need to define proper thread communication.